# Do physical fields always have dimension of the Tangent Space at a point?

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, vector-fields, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

Say we only consider classical fields in 3 dimensions. In a 3 dimensional space you have scalar or vector fields, where scalar fields can be understood as vectors of one dimension. The other physical vector Fields I know of have three dimensions. What about the intermediate? Can 2 dimensional vector fields exist in 3D space and have physical meaning?

Comment: To many questions - none of which have anything to do with title. A scalar has no direction - vectors have direction - hence a scalar is not a vector. A $1$d vector is a vector which lives in a $1$d space, etc. Use whatever is needed to describe the fields.

Comment: I don't see why a scalar cannot be considered a one dimensional vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spin of a particle is an example of a kind of a 2-dimensional vector field in 3D.

Any measurement results in a 1/2 or -1/2 value, and the particle has after it, a state vector "up" or "down".

I said "a kind" of vector, because the components of a 3D vector are modified after a coordinate rotation following rules that are different for the spin state vectors.

That is why they are called spinors instead of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

No, the number of independent components of a field does not have to match the dimensionality of the tangent space. For example, spinor fields have two or four components, and the tensor field for gravitational perturbations has ten components.